# Implement unit test for a sitecore MVC solution with glassmapper

Tags: glass-mapper, unit-testing, fakedb

I have the below scenario to implement unit testing on a `Sitecore MVC` (with glassmapper) integration.

1. We are using a wrapper class to make calls to Glassmapper Sitecore Context methods. Below is one of the example.

   ```
    public interface IMappingProvider
    {
         T GetItem<T>(Guid id, bool isLazy = false, bool inferType = false) where T : class;
        ...
    }

    public class GlassMappingProvider : IMappingProvider
    {
         public T GetItem<T>(Guid id, bool isLazy = false, bool inferType = false) where T : class
         {
              var context = new SitecoreContext();
              return context.GetItem<T>(id, isLazy, inferType);
         }
         ...
    }
   ```
2. All the controllers are being initialized with the wrapper `GlassMappingProvider`

   ```
    public class SitecoreTestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMappingProvider _mappingProvider;

        public SitecoreTestController (IMappingProvider mappingProvider)
        {
            _mappingProvider = mappingProvider;
        }
        ...
    }
   ```
3. I have followed multiple articles where in to create Mock Sitecore Context, create Sitecore Fake DB, create the Item and set in the fake context.
   The challenge I have are bwlow

- Could not pass the Sitecore Context to controllers
- Could not Mock the GetItem of the Glass Wrapper - GlassMappingProvider.

Any one had the similar implementation or any suggestions on what to be done to write a test cases for such a implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below-mentioned steps and try to incorporate them with your existing code:

1. Create a Test controller in your project, for example, I am creating `HeroTestController` and specifying the namespace of your controller:

```
using HeroController = global::YourProjectName.HeroController;
```

2. Define the variables in your Test Class:

```
private Mock<IMvcContext> mvcContextMock;
private Mock<HeroController> controller;
```

3. Initialize those variables into your `TestInitialize` Method:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
 {
   this.mvcContextMock= new Mock<IMvcContext>();
   this.controller = new Mock<HeroController>(this.mvcContextMock.Object) { CallBase = true };
 }
```

4. Write your Test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodA()
 {
   // arrange 
   GetItemByIdOptions option = new GetItemByIdOptions(this.YourObject.Id) { InferType = false, Lazy = Glass.Mapper.LazyLoading.Disabled };
   this.mvcContextMock.Setup(x => x.SitecoreService.GetItem<ModelName>(option))
                .Returns(this.YourObject);

  // act
           
  // assert 
           
}
```

Steps 1,2 and 3 can solve your first problem i.e. `Could not pass the Sitecore Context to controllers`.

Steps 4 can solve your second problem i.e. `Could not Mock the GetItem of the Glass Wrapper - GlassMappingProvider.`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Himmat. I understand that this approach will help creating test cases for any new controller where Sitecore Context is being used. 

But I would need a solution where the existing controllers code can be untouched and implement Test cases as well. 

Once again, Thanks for taking the time and providing a detailed solution with code example